# A good word for the mix of Date Of Birth or "Date Of Birth" of a organization (founding date?)

Tags: synonyms

I guess there is quite some overlap in the concepts. Is there a good word that would work well for both cases?

> Albert Einstein / DateOfBirth
>
> FC Barcelona / DateOfBirth

Comment: I gather names for computing variables are off topic here. As an English synonym question, I doubt whether you’ll get an an answer, but for a field in a data structure I’d use something like “startDate” and get back to your coding.

Comment: Why does it matter if I'm writing a book, a poem or a technical project that I'm looking for synonyms?

Comment: As I said, you may get an answer that is generally valid for the English language, which is the remit of this site. Because I doubt it (I may be wrong, in which case good luck to you) and because I program myself, I suggested a variable name for that purpose only as a comment. Take it or leave it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our Help Center specifically states that picking names, including for `things_used_in_software`, is out of scope for our site.

Comment: Hi @David, 1. I am looking for an English word, not a "technical" word. 2. "and get back to your coding" is the part that I fall over - it's unnecessary scorning. Without that part of the sentence it would be a good  suggestion.

Comment: There is no such thing as a “Date **Of** Birth” because we do not capitalize the word *of* used in headlines or titles alike. Paperwork would normally simply read *Date of birth* or perhaps *Date of Birth*, occasionally *DOB*. Do not capitalize *of*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use *birth* you could use [**origin**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/origin):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2 a** : rise, beginning, or derivation from a source
>   // the *origin* of life on Earth
>   // The word "algebra" is of Arabic *origin*.
>   **2 b** : the point at which something begins or rises or from which it derives
>   // the *origin* of the custom
>   *also* : something that creates, causes, or gives rise to another
>   // a spring is the *origin* of the brook

So, you would have:

> Albert Einstein / DateofOrigin
>   FC Barcelona / DateofOrigin

The word is less idiomatic than others would be in each specific context; but it also seems the best suited to work equally with both. So, you need to trade-off between it being natural and it being generally applicable.

Comment: Tee, hee. Have you done a Google ngram for "Albert Einstein's date of origin"? And does that refer to conception or birth?